# Can an Eldritch Knight's Weapon Bond be with an ammunition?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter

Technically speaking, you can use any object as an improvised weapon, including a ranged weapon's ammunition (ex: arrow).

The Eldritch Knight's Weapon Bond feature does not prohibit improvised weapons to be used for the bond.

Could an Eldritch Knight bond with an ammunition, therefore always having at least one to shoot each turn at the cost of a bonus action?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Rules as intended, No. It has to be an actual weapon.

Jeremy Crawford sent out a his unofficial ruling on this one [over twitter](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/05/16/can-an-eldritch-knight-bond-to-a-shield-or-a-quiver/):

> Weapon Bond works with a bona fide weapon ("Behold, my sword!"), not an improvised weapon ("Look, a stool!").

He later clarified on this exact topic, saying:

> Weapon Bond works with a bow or a crossbow, not with a quiver or an arrow.

Comment: Well, it seems like Crawford outsmarted me again !

Comment: I would add that allowing it as a homerule would not break anything. It costs your bonus action, and the magic from the +1 arrow is lost anyway.

Answer (score 4):

#### Yes, however certain conditions must apply and DM fiat is often required

The sole condition for Weapon Bond is that you must bond a weapon. As you state, ammunition can be used as an Improvised Weapon, however this does *not* directly imply that it is a weapon (more on this below).

Therefore, the ammunition is only eligible when the ammunition as an Improvised Weapon is considered a "true"<sup>1</sup> weapon.

##### When can ammunition as an Improvised Weapon be treated as a weapon?

The rules for Improvised Weapons provide explicit support for classifying Improvised Weapons as weapons, however certain conditions must be met. Consider the following from the rules for Improvised Weapons:

> Often, an improvised weapon is similar to an actual weapon and can be treated as such.

In these cases, if the weapon is "similar" to an actual weapon, the Improvised Weapon is *explicitly* considered the same as that actual weapon, and therefore can be considered as a true weapon. For example, your DM may rule that an arrow is similar enough to a dagger to be used as such (a bodkin head arrow or a crossbow bolt could certainly be used as a stiletto, albeit awkwardly). Similarly, a ballista bolt might be used as a spear or a lance. In both cases, the ammunition can be considered a true weapon and therefore can be used for Weapon Bond.

##### What about unusual ammunition as Improvised Weapons?

Unfortunately the rules do not clearly state whether an Improvised Weapon is *always* considered a weapon. The rule quoted above could be interpreted as a mechanism for *excluding* certain Improvised Weapons from weapon status (e.g. "if it's not similar to weapon, then it isn't a weapon").

On the other hand, an argument could be made that the presence of the word "weapon" in "Improvised Weapon" implies that they are all true weapons, however the rules do not explicitly confirm this. If your DM subscribes to this argument, then the sole condition for Bonding ammunition becomes the following qualifier for an Improvised Weapon:

> An improvised weapon includes any object you can wield in one or two hands, such as broken glass, a table leg, a frying pan, a wagon wheel, or a dead goblin.

Personally, I would be hard pressed to consider a goblin corpse as a weapon (let alone ammunition), but if your DM and your table are okay with it, then the rules support this.

---

<sup>1</sup>: "true weapon" is not a real game term, however for clarity's sake I've chosen to use this phrase to indicate when something is explicitly considered as a weapon via 5e's rules.